# Subtract a SUM value from a regular number to get a total in using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am setting up a "target" display field in my application. The target for this example is 12000KG (We Process Electronic Waste). I used MySQL SUM function to tally up all the weights inputted by my staff, now i want to take the 12000KG target, and subtract it from the SUM value to get the difference so staff can see how far off they are from the actual 12000KG target. How do i go about doing this?

```
 <h3>Target: 12000KG</h3>
           <h3>Current Value: <?php
$dbConnection = new PDO('mysql:dbname=ecemsmaster;host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8', 'ecemsmaster', 'ecemsmaster');
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

//The COUNT SQL statement that we will use.
$sql = "SELECT MONTH(date), SUM(subgrade + castaluminium + copper + stainlesssteel + plastic + brass + batteries + cables + lowgradePCB + mediumgradePCB + highgradePCB) AS num FROM daily_recyclables where MONTH(date)=MONTH(curdate())";
 
//Prepare the COUNT SQL statement.
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare($sql);

//Execute the COUNT statement.
$stmt->execute();

//Fetch the row that MySQL returned.
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//The $row array will contain "num". Print it out.
echo $row['num'];
?> KG</h3>
            <h3>Over/Under Target: **-1000KG**</h3>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the correct way to do it, but it worked for me.

I just added "-12000" by the echo $row['num'];

```
<?php
$dbConnection = new PDO('mysql:dbname=ecemsmaster;host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8', 'ecemsmaster', 'ecemsmaster');
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

//The COUNT SQL statement that we will use.
$sql = "SELECT MONTH(date), SUM(subgrade + castaluminium + copper + stainlesssteel + plastic + brass + batteries + cables + lowgradePCB + mediumgradePCB + highgradePCB) AS num FROM daily_recyclables where MONTH(date)=MONTH(curdate())";
 
//Prepare the COUNT SQL statement.
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare($sql);

//Execute the COUNT statement.
$stmt->execute();

//Fetch the row that MySQL returned.
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//The $row array will contain "num". Print it out.
echo $row['num'];
?> KG</h3>
            <h3>Over/Under Target:  <?php
$dbConnection = new PDO('mysql:dbname=ecemsmaster;host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8', 'ecemsmaster', 'ecemsmaster');
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

//The COUNT SQL statement that we will use.
$sql = "SELECT MONTH(date), SUM(subgrade + castaluminium + copper + stainlesssteel + plastic + brass + batteries + cables + lowgradePCB + mediumgradePCB + highgradePCB) AS num FROM daily_recyclables where MONTH(date)=MONTH(curdate())";
 
//Prepare the COUNT SQL statement.
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare($sql);

//Execute the COUNT statement.
$stmt->execute();

//Fetch the row that MySQL returned.
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//The $row array will contain "num". Print it out.
echo $row['num']-12000;
?>
```